# Google Maps API ( Get Locations Near Lat Lon )

Tags: api, maps

when a user types a real world address into our website. We grab the latitude and longitude using a script , and use this to propagate a gMap.

However what I would like to do, is ...

If user types into search box, a suburb ( that is in our DB )
And clicks a checkBox , to include surrounding suburbs, how we could set a proximity code to search for that suburb , grab the lat and long and also return results for other addresses within that radius , or  in essence Get Locations near Lat and Long.

Does this make sense, ? I have been scrabbling around on Google all day, with no real luck.

I am sure there must be a way, or API or some formula, for displaying search results of locations within the vicinity of the original LAT LONG geo location.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the 'Google Places API' which is in 'limited developer preview', you have to request the required credentials to use it. See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/ for the details.

Comment: Thanks, have applied for developer api key

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Yahoo's service to find places nearby according to Flickr, try the test console at http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20flickr.places%20where%20lat%3D43%20and%20lon%3D-94